# UINavigationController "forwarding" a pushViewController

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a question to UINavigationControllers. I am not sure how to express what I am trying to do, so I'll just give it a shot. :) I have a working UINavigationController hierarchy. It works fine.

I however have a situation where the "pushed" ViewController class is not to display anything itself, but instead to determine which child ViewController to "forward" the push to.

```
MasterVC -> DeciderVC -> forwards to fooVC
or                    -> forwards to barVC
```

I want to basically redirect the `[self.navigationController pushViewController:DeciderVC animated:NO]` using the logic to either `[self.navigationController pushViewController:fooVC animated:NO]` or `barVC`

The I could hardcode it into the MasterVC, but the point is that I want to reuse DeciderVC with different scenarios, while keeping MasterVC, fooVC and barVC untouched. How do I best go about doing this?

Thanks

**EDIT:** 
A small clarification on the workflow: 
`MasterVC` displays a few possible function-sets.
If the user selects function-set A, then `DeciderObjectA` gets called and in-turn pushes `fooVC`, records the data, then pushes `barVC`, collects the data and then pushes `barVC` again and collects the data. Afterwards `DeciderObjectA` processes that data.
If the user selects function-set B, the `DeciderObjectB` gets called and in-turn pushes `barVC` first followed by `fooVC` and then processes the data.
The DeciderObjects respond differently to the same delegate methods declared in `@protocol` in both `fooVC` and `barVC`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DeciderViewController is not displaying anything, why does it has to be an `UIViewController`? In my eyes a simple `NSObject` which checks a strategy and decides which Controller to push next should be enough. In your terms you have code in the MasterVC that decides which one to push. (I do not understand what the benefit is of having an `UIViewController` in between. Please elaborate if I am missing something.)

```
MasterVC -> fooVC 
MasterVC -> barVC
```

Comment: Good point, I agree completely. So I changed Decider to `NSObject`. I pass the `self.navigationController` from MasterVC to Decider `self.parentController` (instance variable) so I can access the global navigationController. 
I then call `pushViewController:fooVC` on it and it works. My problem is now that I have a delegate method defined in fooVC's `protocol` and it does not get called in Decider, even though it is implemented.

Comment: More concretely if I send a message from within fooVC to `[self.delegate someMethod]` I get an `unrecognized selector sent to instnance`, eventhough it is implemented in Decider.m and I also set the delegate after allocating and initing `fooVC`

Comment: Okay. I think it is better if you push your ViewController still from the MasterVC and not the DeciderObject. The DeciderObject, whether it is a new class or some inline code, just makes the decision. Pushing a ViewController should be performed within a ViewController. Then you also do not have to reset delegates and so on. And self.delegate is not nil?

Comment: I can't do that because I have different DeciderObjects, that all use fooVC and barVC in different orders and process the data collected in fooVC and barVC differently. The DeciderObject not only decides which VC to show but also knows how to deal with the returned data. If I were to put it all in the MasterVC, then a) it wouldn't work since the delegate methods are called the same even though the data is to be used differently and b) MasterVC would become very bloated. After creation, I set `fooVC.delegate = self` in the DeciderObject.

Comment: Ok, I understand. It is getting difficult now for my to find the bug ;). I'll try to have some more thoughts on it.

Comment: About the delegate. Are you sure the DeciderObject still exists when you are at the fooVC? Are you keeping the object on a strong reference? Or else it will be disposed by the garbage collector after you finish the method.

Comment: @pedros that was it... I had an `autorelease` when I alloc inited DeciderObject, after I removed that, the delegate methods worked! THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Can `DeciderVC` simply forward everything on to `foo` or `bar`? Could you not simply instantiate the appropriate one in `viewDidLoad` for `Decider` and assign it's `view` to the `Decider`'s view?

E.g.

```
Decider.m
- (void) viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated {
...
UIViewController *fooVC = [[FooVC alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:fooVC.view];
...
}
```